# Having trouble removing specific values of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, filter, numbers

So, what Iam triyng to do is remove some specific values of a list of strings, I've tried to use regex to no sucess, i want to  remove all values that doesnt have a decimal house, i cant just get the numbers from a certain index because the position of the int number varies.

Here's an example of the list

```
['178', '34,79', '135925,82', '135926,82']
['102021', '191', '135067,69', '858,13', '859,13']
['176054330', '12', '506', '858,13', '0,00', '1,00']
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
re.compile(r'\d{1,5},\d{2}.*')
vend_values = list(filter(r.match, vend_name))
```

To get this result:

```
['34,79', '135925,82', '135926,82']
['135067,69', '858,13', '859,13']
['858,13', '0,00', '1,00']
```

But with that it ends up removing some lines as well

Comment: Why regex then? Try `[i for i in vend_name if not i.isdigit()]`, it will discard items that only consist of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use something as fancy as regex. In python, the `in` keyword will do the work for you. You can use list comprehension too:

```
my_list = ['102021', '191', '135067,69', '858,13', '859,13']
my_filtered_list = [s for s in my_list if ',' in s]
```

if you want to turn this into a function:

```
def list_sorter(input_list):
    return [s for s in input_list if ',' in s]
```

Hope that helps!